# Multiple backgrounds with CSS

Tags: css, background

I try to create element with custom background in CSS but only one background is visible.

```
#myElement  {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%), url('../img/custom-bg.png');
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%), url('../img/custom-bg.png');
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%), url('../img/custom-bg.png');
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%), url('../img/custom-bg.png');
}
```

when I open it in browser `#myElement` has only gradient fill. It's not showing `custom-bg.png`

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you gradient is over the `custom-bg.png` image. Try to move `url('../img/custom-bg.png')` first and then put gradient.

Your code will lok like this:

```
#myElement  {
    background-image: url('../img/custom-bg.png'), -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%);
    background-image: url('../img/custom-bg.png'), -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%);
    background-image: url('../img/custom-bg.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%);
    background-image: url('../img/custom-bg.png'), linear-gradient(bottom, #727d9a -25%, #4b5263 10.3%, #3d4351 50%, #424856 50.37%, #767e90 91.16%, #d2dfff 125%);
}
```